# foreach ($_POST['...']) not working on different PHP version

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm having problem running this code on my server.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="event[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="event[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="event[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="event[]">
```

....

```
if(isset($_POST['event'])){ 
  foreach($_POST['event'] as $value) {
    echo $value."<br>";
  }
}
```

I've tested the code in my localhost (PHP version 5.2.6) and it works. But when I ran it in my server (PHP version 5.5.9) it doesn't seem to work (no output) and I couldn't find any error. Could it be because of the PHP version?

Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please post the entire form.

Comment: This is typo use echo $value."<br>"; instead of echo $event."<br>";

Comment: **"it doesn't seem to work"**, can you please elaborate??

Comment: can you paste your complete code here, i mean html page on which you have this element "event" is.

Comment: By the way, you also have two checkboxes having the same value of `2` :)

Comment: First, you could do a better check of your user input...
`if( !empty($_POST['event']) && is_array($_POST['event']) ) {`
Then display the right variable, $event is not defined here.
To debug your code, you could use Firebug to know if values are well-passed to the server and you could display the content of $_POST with `var_dump($_POST);` to know if they are received.

Comment: @Loenix - thanks for the suggestion. Apparently, the problem was at the form validation. Thanks to everyone for prompt reply :)

Answer (score 0):

another way for doing this hope this will help

```
<?php if(!empty($_POST['event'])){
$count=count($_POST['event']); 
for ($i=0; $i<$count ; $i++) { 
    echo $_POST['event'][$i]."<br/>";
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try count() function instead of isset() function to test array.

// Code goes here

```
if(count($_POST['event']) > 0){ 
  foreach($_POST['event'] as $value) {
    echo $event."<br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not an answer... OP is assigning value to `$value` variable and echoing `$event`...

Comment: If the user doesn't select any of the checkboxes the `$_POST['even']` would be undefined and will cause some warnings!